# Como acessar um valor do JSON e inserir em data-id?

Tags: json

Tenho esse JSON:

```
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 16, recordsFiltered: 16, data: [,…]}
```

e dentro do `data`, por exemplo um registro:

```
0: ["1", "FooBar", "00.000.000/0000-00", "13600-000", "Rua Santos Dumont", "Curitiba", "Jardim X", "ID_1"]
```

Como eu posso pegar **só o número** do ID_1 e colocar nesse `data-id`:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id:"**COLOCAR AQUI**" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só precisas de iterar `obj.data` e gerar um `<a>` com o indice do array.

Exemplo:

```js
var obj = {
  draw: 1,
  recordsTotal: 16,
  recordsFiltered: 16,
  data: [
    ["1", "FooBar", "00.000.000/0000-00", "13600-000", "Rua Santos Dumont", "Curitiba", "Jardim X", "ID_1"]
  ]
}

obj.data.forEach(function(data) {
  var a = '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal" data-id= "' + data[7] + '" id="getPublication" class="blue"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-search-plus bigger-130">' + data[4] + '</i></a>';
  document.body.innerHTML += a;
});
```